# Why does the sort() JavaScript function works in Firefox but not in Chromium?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, chromium

I have been debugging my JavaScript code for two days and now I found that it works in Firefox.

I uploaded the code into jsFiddle so you can test it [there](http://jsfiddle.net/Rx6jQ/3/).

It works perfect in Firefox v23 but it doesn't sort in Chromium v28.0.1500.71. I'm using jQuery v1.10.1

I don't know if the error is on the `sort()` function or maybe in the jQuery library.

Should this be reported as a bug in Chromium?

```js
var data = {
    "list": [
        {
            "title": "a",
            "date": "03/08/2010"
        },
        {
            "title": "b",
            "date": "31/07/2010",
        },
        {
            "title": "c",
            "date": "08/08/2010",
        },
        {
            "title": "d",
            "date": "01/08/2010"
        },
        {
            "title": "e",
            "date": "11/12/2010"
        },
        {
            "title": "f",
            "date": "10/12/2010"
        },
        {
            "title": "g",
            "date": "12/12/2010"
        },
        {
            "title": "h",
            "date": "14/12/2010"
        },
        {
            "title": "i",
            "date": "11/12/2010"
        },
        {
            "title": "j",
            "date": "05/08/2010"
        },
        {
            "title": "k",
            "date": "03/08/2010"
        }
    ]
};
// Sort
$.each(data, function (key, val) {
    val.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.title.toLowerCase() > b.title.toLowerCase();
    });
    // The object is not sorted here
});
// Print
document.querySelector("pre").textContent = 
    JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this :

```
$.each(data, function (key, val) {
    val.sort(function(a, b) {
        return a.title.toLowerCase().localeCompare(b.title.toLowerCase());
    });
});

$("pre").text( JSON.stringify(data, null, 4) );
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Rx6jQ/4/)

`localeCompare` returns a number indicating whether a reference string comes before or after or is the same as the given string in sort order, in other words it returns -1, 1 or 0, while comparing strings with `<` or `>` returns true or false, which is not what `sort()` is expecting.

Answer (score 3):

Your `sort` comparer is broken.

The `sort` callback is expected to return a negative number, `0`, or a positive number, depending on whether the first argument is smaller than, equal to, or larger than the second.

You're always returning a boolean, which is not what it's supposed to do.

Comment: It's probably just the way that they implemented it. Perhaps Firefox interprets False as 0 and True as 1, while Chromium does not automatically convert their boolean values to integer values which would allow the sorting to work in Firefox only - I don't know for certain, this is just my best guess.